# What is the best logic for making the Filtering System like in Excel?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface

I have a list String array to hold tabular data, we knew in advanced there 2 fields Item & its price:

```
String[] myArr1={"car","12014"};
String[] myArr2={"book","120"};
String[] myArr3={"chair","500"};
String[] myArr4={"car","510"};
String[] myArr5={"book","50"};
```

All the above String array should be put into a List.

Then I want to make a filtering system that is similar to Excel, for example, when user clicks on the Item column then a Panel will popup & looks like this:

```
Exter Text:_____ (a textbox that user can type in data & the List should show 
only rows that match that data)

(A List of check boxes of ALL UNIQUE text in the Item column, if user 
uncheck then all the rows that contain that data will be removed, just like in Excel.)

[x] Car
[x] Book
[x] Chair
```

This question is not about a particular language as I just want to know the logic for building this system. The logic should be elegant, simple , sound & easy for coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would store a bag (`Set` in Java) of the column's values.  `LinkedHashSet` in Java will store them in the order entered, so you could alphabetize the values.  This would be metadata about the values in the column.

The advantage to this is that `Set`s are quickly accessible, and will only allow unique values, so your list of unique values will not grow at the same rate as your values in the column (unless all the values are unique)

Comment: too brief, i need more info

Comment: What more info do you need?

Comment: when users type data in the textbox the system need to  check or uncheck the data accordingly, how to do that elegantly?

Comment: Well, you have a list of values.  Assuming the values in your column are not in any particular order, you'll just have to iterate over it and check the boxes that need checking.  If the values in the column are ordered then you can save some time using one of many search algorithms